# How to a, b = myClass(a, b) in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterable-unpacking, magic-function

Python does this:

```
t = (1, 2)
x, y = t
# x = 1
# y = 2
```

How can I implement my class so to do

```
class myClass():
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

mc = myClass(1, 2)
x, y = mc
# x = 1
# y = 2
```

Is there a magic function I could implement in order to achieve this?

Comment: `tuple(1, 2)` is not a valid `tuple` call.

Comment: @user2357112 I fixed it, along with the `__init__` method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make your class [iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable). Do this by adding the `__iter__` method to it.

```
class myClass():
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter([self.a, self.b])

mc = myClass(1, 2)

x, y = mc

print(x, y)
```

Output:

```
1 2
```

Comment: What about a meta-scope where I can do this ? myClass_atrributename = myClass(a, b). So if your class has an attribute named “myClass_attributename” to return that value

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood that

Comment: I think @entropyfeverone might be trying to refer to `getattr`? Like `getattr(myclass(a, b), 'myClass_attributename')`

Answer (score 1):

If your class doesn't do much else, you might prefer to use a [named tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple):

```
from collections import namedtuple

MyClass = namedtuple('MyClass', 'a b')
mc = MyClass(1, 2)
print(mc.a, mc.b)  # -> 1 2
x, y = mc
print(x, y)  # -> 1 2
```

BTW, style note: Class names should be UpperCamelCase.